# awsのs3は独自ドメインでssl対応できますか?

Tags: aws, ssl, amazon-s3, https

お名前.comでとっているドメインがあります。
ここでは`example.com`とします。

awsのs3に画像ファイルを置いて、`https://img.example.com/`というURLでアクセスできるようにしたいのですが、可能でしょうか。
s3は標準でsslに対応してるとの事なので、ネームサーバーの設定だけでいけるのかなと思っているのですが、やったことがないのでわかりません。

aws側で必要な準備と、それ以外で必要な準備、注意点などを教えていただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

残念ながらS3ではできないですね。

S3の手前にCloudFrontを利用してはどうでしょうか？CloudFrontは独自ドメイン名の証明書を割り当てる仕組みもあります。

この場合の注意点は、CloudFrontのデフォルトキャッシュ期間は24時間のため、そのままですと24時間以内の変更が反映されない場合が出てきます。S3に保管したファイルにキャッシュヘッダを指定すればCloudFrontがキャッシュする時間も指定することができます。

補足として
CloudFrontのSSLは、「専用 IP 独自 SSL」の場合 月額 600USドル 掛かります。
「SNI 独自 SSL」の場合は、別途費用は掛かりませんが、古いブラウザはサポートしていません。